# How can I extract specific data from e-prime output (.txt file)

Tags: python

Been learning Python the last couple of days for the function of completing a data extraction. I'm not getting anywhere & hope one of you lovely people can advise.

I need to extract data that follows: RESP, CRESP, RTTime and RT.

Here's a snippit for an example of the mess I have to deal with.

Thoughts?

```
Level: 4
        *** LogFrame Start ***
        Procedure: ActProcScenarios
        No: 1
        Line1: It is almost time for your town's spring festival.  A friend of yours is
        Line2: on the committee and asks if you would be prepared to help out with the
        Line3: barbecue in the park.  There is a large barn for use if it rains.
        Line4: You hope that on that day it will be
        pfrag: s-n-y
        pword: sunny
        pletter: u
        Quest: Does the town have an autumn festival?
        Correct: {LEFTARROW}
        ScenarioListPract: 1
        Topic: practice
        Subtheme: practice
        ActPracScenarios: 1
        Running: ActPracScenarios
        ActPracScenarios.Cycle: 1
        ActPracScenarios.Sample: 1
        DisplayFragInstr.OnsetDelay: 17
        DisplayFragInstr.OnsetTime: 98031
        DisplayFragInstr.DurationError: -999999
        DisplayFragInstr.RTTime: 103886
        DisplayFragInstr.ACC: 0
        DisplayFragInstr.RT: 5855
        DisplayFragInstr.RESP: {DOWNARROW}
        DisplayFragInstr.CRESP: 
        FragInput.OnsetDelay: 13
        FragInput.OnsetTime: 103899
        FragInput.DurationError: -999999
        FragInput.RTTime: 104998
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I took the liberty of reformatting your post - is it correct like this? Also, could you tell us which part of this problem you're having trouble with? Reading the file? Finding the correct line(s)? Finding the relevant values in those lines? It's always good to include the code you already have, so we can show which parts need work...

Comment: That's perfect thank you, & thanks for your answer! 
I understand what the code you kindly supplied does, however I'm having trouble implementing it. 
 I obviously have to read the desired .txt file:
ep = open ('t1.txt.')
 & then surely it should be a matter of running the code with myfile replaced by 'ep'. Am I missing something critically basic, as nothing happens?

 Thank you for your patience  :)

Comment: Your approach looks correct to me. The regex is rather strict in that it requires a space character to be there after the colon; if that's not present (or maybe a tab instead), then the regex wouldn't match. Perhaps try `print`ing the lines before matching them to see if the file really contains what you think it does, and that Python is reading it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regular expressions would be the right tool here because the `\b` [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) allow you to make sure that `RESP` only matches a whole word `RESP` and not just part of a longer word (like `CRESP`).

Something like this should get you started:

```
>>> import re
>>> for line in myfile:
...     match = re.search(r"\b(RT|RTTime|RESP|CRESP): (.*)", line)
...     if match:
...         print("Matched {0} with value {1}".format(match.group(1),
...                                                   match.group(2)))
```

Output:

```
Matched RTTime with value 103886
Matched RT with value 5855
Matched RESP with value {DOWNARROW}
Matched CRESP with value
Matched RTTime with value 104998
```

Answer (score 1):

transform it to a dict first, then just get items from the dict as you wish

```
d = {k.strip(): v.strip() for (k, v) in 
                    [line.split(':') for line in s.split('\n') if line.find(':') != -1]}
print (d['DisplayFragInstr.RESP'], d['DisplayFragInstr.CRESP'], 
       d['DisplayFragInstr.RTTime'], d['DisplayFragInstr.RT'])

>>> ('{DOWNARROW}', '', '103886', '5855')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be making things harder for yourself than needed. E-prime has a file format called .edat that is designed for the purpose you are describing. An edat file is another format that contains the same information as the .txt file but it a way that makes extracting variables easier. I personally only use the type of text file you have posted here as a form of data storage redundancy.

If you are doing things this way because you do not have a software key, it might help to know that the E-Merge and E-DataAid programs for eprime don't require a key. You only need the key for editing build files. Whoever provided you with the .txt files should probably have an install disk for these programs. If not, it is available on the PST website (I believe you need a serial code to create an account, but not certain)

Eprime generally creates a .edat file that matches the content of the text file you have posted an example of. Sometimes though if eprime crashes you don't get the edat file and only have the .txt. Luckily you can generate the edat file from the .txt file.

Here's how I would approach this issue: If you do not have the edat files available first use E-DataAid to recover the files.

Then presuming you have multiple participants you can use e-merge to merge all of the edat files together for all participants in who completed this task.

Open the merged file. It might look a little chaotic depending on how much you have in the file. You can got to Go to tools->Arrange columns This will show a list of all your variables. Adjust so that only the desired variables are in the right hand box. Hit ok.

Looking at the file you posted it says level 4 at the top so I'm guessing there are a lot of procedures in this experiment. If you have many procedures in the program you might at this point have lines that just have startup info and NULL in the locations where your variables or interest are. You and fix this by going to tools->filter and creating a filter to eliminate those lines. Sometimes also depending on file structure you might also end up with duplicate lines of the same data. You can also fix this with filtering.

You can then export this file as a csv

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pprint


def parse_logs(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    base_regex = r'^.*{0}: (.*)$'
    match_terms = ["RESP", "CRESP", "RTTime", "RT"]

    regexes = {term: base_regex.format(term) for term in match_terms}

    output_list = []
    for line in lines:
        for key, regex in regexes.items():
            match = re.match(regex, line)
            if match:
                match_tuple = (key, match.groups()[0])
                output_list.append(match_tuple)
    return output_list

pprint.pprint(parse_logs("respregex"))
```

**Edit:** Tim and Guy's answers are both better. I was in a hurry to write something and missed two much more elegant solutions.